# Access local network files with android

Tags: java, android, file, networking, nas

I want to acces files on my LAN (on a NAS or PC) by an Android app like I can do on Windows by typing \pcname\ in the explorer. I know this is possible on Android, because there are other apps that do this (e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm).

I already tried accessing the file as a local file (new File("\\pcname\")). Needless to say this did not work. I searched the web for tutorials, but every tutorial I found was using ftp, http and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using java.net.URL you can use ftp urls like `ftp://servername/path/to/file`. To access windows share, you need to use the SMB protocol (there is similar question: [How to access share folder in windows through android and read files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389366/how-to-access-share-folder-in-windows-through-android-and-read-files) )

Comment: Thanks! I used the jar from the jcifs library (http://jcifs.samba.org/src/jcifs-1.3.17.zip) and this example http://lists.samba.org/archive/jcifs/2007-September/007465.html. At first I got aa ExceptionInInitializerError (maybe because I did run the code in the main thread for testing), which could be solved by ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX; StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);.