# How to send image files to NAS server in my application?

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream, smb, nas

I want to send image files (jpg, png) to [NAS server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage) in java using [smb](https://jcifs.samba.org)

I have added the [jcifs-1.3.19.jar](https://download.samba.org/pub/samba/stable/samba-4.5.1.tar.gz). as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389366/how-to-access-share-folder-in-windows-through-android-and-read-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222219/access-local-network-files-with-android)

Edit: I have successfully sent jpeg image to a shared folder on server using this code, but the speed is very slow, its sending almost 1kb/second. Any Solution??

```
    static final String USER_NAME = "Waqas";
    static final String PASSWORD = "mypass";
    static final String NETWORK_FOLDER = "smb://DESKTOP-LAP/Users/Waqas/";

      public boolean copyFiles(FileInputStream file, String fileName) {
        boolean successful = false;
        int cursor;
        SmbFileOutputStream sfos;
        SmbFile sFile;
        String path;
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth;
        try{
            String user = USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD;    
             auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX; StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
             path = NETWORK_FOLDER + fileName;    
             sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
             sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);

            while((cursor = file.read())!=-1){
                sfos.write(cursor);
            }
            successful = true;
            System.out.println("Successful " + successful);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            successful = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return successful;
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with just send a `jpg` file?
You can use the `inputStream` class for reading the file and send the data to the NAS using the `SmbFileOutputStream`

Comment: I have updated the code, please check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally here is the solution:

```
  public boolean copyFiles(FileInputStream file, String fileName) {
            boolean successful = false;
            int cursor;
            SmbFileOutputStream sfos;
            SmbFile sFile;
            String path;
            NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth;
            try{
                String user = USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
                System.out.println("User: " + user);

                 auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.LAX; StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);

                 path = NETWORK_FOLDER + fileName+".jpeg";
                System.out.println("Path: " +path);

                 sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);
                 sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);

                long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();

                byte[] b = new byte[8192];
                int n, tot = 0;
                Log.d("asdf","initiating : total="+tot);


                while((n = file.read(b))>0){
                    sfos.write( b, 0, n );
                    tot += n;
                    Log.d("asdf","writing : total="+tot);
                }
                successful = true;
                Log.d("asdf","Successful : total="+tot);

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                successful = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("asdf","exxeption ");

            }
            return successful;
        }
```

Comment: (like)
BTW you don't need to use `SmbFile` if the path is a local path.