# write a file to a network drive with Android?

Tags: java, android

i have a program that writes a log file among others.
Now I have written it as an Android application.
With the .jar file on my computer I have no problem accessing the file.

Java code:

```
static final String PATH = "\\\\192.168.1.1\\VolumeX\\log.lst";
File f = new File (PATH);
FileUtils.write (f, "textToWrite", true);
```

As an android app (the mobile phone is connected to the same network) i was not able to access this file.
I always get an IOException while i try to write the file with the Android application.

I hope someone can help me and give me a tip on how I should do it right.
sorry for my bad english and thanks for your help.

Comment: I highly doubt that Android has a built-in SMB client.

Answer (score 0):

As Slaks said, you need samba to connect to a network share. Maybe this question can help you implement it:
[Write/upload a file using Samba/JCIFS issue (SmbAuthException: Access is denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559019/write-upload-a-file-using-samba-jcifs-issue-smbauthexception-access-is-denied)

Comment: Thanks @both 
ye right i forgot communication between linux and windoof... 
anyway it works now :)